# min-width property having issue in IE8 Compatibility mode

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, ie8-compatibility-mode

Have a **parent DIV** with a class **.list** attached. **Paretnt DIV** consist of **8 floated divs** with **position:relative** property.

Parent Div has **min-width** property, when i open the page in **IE8 compatibility mode** its considering the **min-width** property as **width** property and shows all the 8 DIVS in a row. Where in it should show only 3 divs.

Here is the HTML code

```
<div id="list-container">
<div class='list'>
            <div class='item'><h1>1</h1></div>
            <div class='item'><h1>2</h1></div>
            <div class='item'><h1>3</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="item"><h1>4</h1>
            </div>
            <div class='item'><h1>5</h1>
            </div>
            <div class='item'><h1>6</h1>
            </div>
            <div class='item'><h1>7</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="item"><h1>8</h1>
            </div>

        </div>
</div>
```

CSS Code

```
.list{
    background:grey;
    min-width:1400px;
    float:left;
}

.item{
    background:green;
    width:140px;
    height:80px;
    margin:5px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
#list-container {
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
width: 450px;
```

}

It works perfect in Firefox.

UPDATE: I see the same issue in IE7 as well (using IE8 brower and switching the browser mode to IE7 from Developer tool)

**EDIT :For more Clarity am adding images**

IE7 and IE8 compatibility mode

[image]

FF

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: i m check if ie but not problum

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the parent container with a lower amount of width with its child elements. It will always show quirky in some ways. Also ie8 doesn't support min-width. Try removing the min-width.

We could be much more of help if you show us what you really wanted to do.

Comment: @Janharold.. Thanks for taking time for my question.. :). Am trying to show only 3 Child DIVS at a time, using JQuery and have animated to slide each div at a time interval of 5 seconds. In IE7 and IE8 compatibility mode all the 8 divs are getting displayed. Expected is only 3 should be shown.

Comment: Yeah, try removing the min-width first. Also, why did you set overflow:hidden on the parent?

Answer (score 0):

For IE you should add `* html .yourclass{height: 1%;}` to fix. Did you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

You are inheriting the wrong class, make parent and child in difference, that will help for sure :)
have look at fiddle

```
   link:  http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/gu3Us/1/
```

thank you,